# What happens if I feel my bounty question is still unanswered and date expires?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties

What happens if I feel my bounty question is still unanswered but someone has answered it, but that answer is not the correct one and the time expires?

Comment: The bounty expires. It may be auto-awarded. That's it.

Comment: @Lance: why the reopen? The automatic award system is described in the linked question, I'm not really sure what more could be added.

Comment: The question isn't about the technical specifics of how the bounty system works, but is looking for input on what someone could do next once it hasn't worked for them.  It's really a discussion question.

Comment: you start farming rep to prepare for [next, usually 2X larger bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/238594/revisions "see example here")

Comment: Sorry that your question got closed, some people close questions because they don't really understand the site or empathize with new users.  Hope you're able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You then will need to do what's necessary to draw attention to your question, which probably includes editing it to be better and offering another bounty on it.  Here's a question that addresses a lot of that.

[Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)